# Return two different data types based on condition from the same method

Tags: java, design-patterns

Looking for the best strategy to handle a method returns two different data types based on condition

```
public Response find(int id) {

Student std = studentService.findOne(empId):

if(std == null)
    return new ErrorResponse(errorCode);
else
   return new SuccessResponse(std);  

}
```

One condition is like I cannot implement an Interface for ErrorResponse or SuccessResponse.

Another condition is like I cannot have a parent class for this.

These classes are dynamically generated classes by other Clients

Comment: No parent classes

Comment: In your example, is `Response` the parent of both `ErrorResponse` and `SuccessResponse`? If so, what's the problem?

Comment: Best way is to fix the system.

Comment: In your condition it looks like you can only return object Huch is not great - where those constraints coming from?

Comment: "Another condition is like I cannot have a parent class for this." .
what do you mean by "this" ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 Class Response {
  private ErrorResponse error;
  private SuccessResponse success;
 }


 public Response find(int id) {
 Response res = new Response();
  Student std = studentService.findOne(empId):
  if (std == null)
    res.set(new ErrorResponse(errorCode));
  else
    return res.set(new SuccessResponse(std));
 }
```

I think maybe good to use Optional of ErrorResponse and SuccessResponse

Comment: Response act like a DTO, the Parent class https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/inheritance-in-java/